# Passing string Argument, read from a file

Tags: c++, regex

I am Trying to find a `regex` pattern in a text. Let's call the text: the original Text.
The following is the code for the `patternFinder()` program:

```
vector <pair <long,long> >CaddressParser::patternFinder(string pattern)

{


        string m_text1=m_text;
        int begin =0;
        int end=0;
        smatch m;
        regex e (pattern); 



    vector<pair<long, long>> indices;
    if(std::regex_search(m_text1,m,e))
    {
        begin=m.position();
        end=m.position()+m.length()-1;
        m_text1 = m.suffix().str();
        indices.push_back(make_pair(begin,end));
        while(end<m_length&&std::regex_search(m_text1,m,e))
            { 
                begin=end+m.prefix().length()+1;
                end=end+m.prefix().length()+m.length();
                indices.push_back(make_pair(begin,end));
                m_text1 = m.suffix().str();

            }
        return indices;
    }

    else return indices;
}
```

I have the following `regular Expression`:

```
"\\b[0-9]{3}\\b.*(Street).*[0-9]{5}"
```

and the Original text mentioned at the beginning is:

- way 10.01.2013 ***700 West Market Street OH 35611*** asdh

and only the bold text is supposed to match the regex.
Now the Problem is when the regex is passed as a string which has been read from a text file the `patternFinder()` does not recognize the pattern.Though when a direct string (which is identical to the one in the text file) is passed as an argument to `patternFinder()` it works.
Where could this problem coming from?

The following is the code of my `fileReader()` function which I don't think is very relevant to mention:

```
string CaddressParser::fileReader(string fileName)
{

    string text;
    FILE *fin;
    fin=fopen(fileName.c_str(),"rb" );
    int length=getLength(fileName);
    char *buffer= new char[length];
    fread(buffer,length,1,fin);
    buffer[length]='\0';
    text =string(buffer);
    fclose(fin);

    return text;

}
```

Comment: If you have `char *buffer = new char[length]`, you really should not access `buffer[length]`, it's after the end of array. Make it bigger: `char *buffer = new char[length+1]`

Comment: Can you show the exact content of the file (the one containing the regex)? I'm asking because when read from a file, you need single backslashes instead of double ones, of course.

Comment: @Angew thanks for your answer that's where the problem was. If you want you can write your solution as an answer and i can accept it so that others can use it too.

Comment: @fery Done. But note that the others' comments about buffer size are indeed valid - an array created by `new char[length]` has valid indices `[0]`, `[1]` ... `[length - 1]` only.

Comment: i have got that a lot but somehow when i read a file the last character of the file gets stored in the position [length-1] and storing the '0' character in the position [length] does not give any errors .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there is an apparent syntactic difference when writing the regex directly into C++ code and when reading it from a file.

In C++, the backslash character has escape semantics, so to put a literal backslash into a string literal, you must escape it itself with a backslash. So to get a a two-character string `\b` in memory, you have to use a string literal `"\\b"`. The two backslashes are interpreted by the C++ compiler as a single backslash character to be stored in the literal. In other words, `strlen("\\b")` is 2.

On the other hand, contents of a text file are read by your program and never processed by the C++ compiler. So to get the two characters `\` and `b` into a string read from a file, write just the two-character string `\b` into the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the function reading the string from the file. Print the string read and make sure the regular expression is being read correctly.

Comment: could you run it on your own PC . Because i have been using this fileReader() for other purposes and it worked just fine.

Comment: @fery sorry, I can not run the code at the moment. By the way aamir has pointed out your mistake already.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in these 2 lines
    buffer[length]='\0';
    text =string(buffer);

buffer[length] should have been buffer[length - 1]